# Bitcoin-qt on Elementary OS Loki

Tags: installation

I'm very new to Elementary OS and I used the version Freya a short time. There I got Bitcoin-qt easily out of the repositories.
On Elementary OS isn't that that simple - has anyone experienced the same?

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
sudo apt-get update
```

The tags above aren´t working on Loki.
I just want to know - I have no problem to download the .tar.gz and start it from there.

Comment: What error message do you get when you try?

Comment: Hi!

I get this one:

sudo: add-apt-repository: Befehl nicht gefunden

Comment: Have you tried this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/493460/how-to-install-add-apt-repository-using-the-terminal

Comment: Thanks a alot - This worked perfectly:

apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bitcoin-qt

Comment: @brandy: Since you're answering your own question after solving it, please post your comment as an answer instead. :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a alot - I found the solution:

This worked perfectly:

```
apt-get install software-properties-common 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin 
sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install bitcoin-qt
```